# simplexml_load_file 403 Forbidden

Tags: php, youtube

`Warning: simplexml_load_file(http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/b3a5BgqObEY): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden`

is the error that I get with the youtube feed in my site. I was told it was because a YouTube video was removed, but I don't know enough about PHP to fix this error. Can someone help push me in the right direction? When I searched for this error, all that came up was xml stuff and this is all in php so that doesn't help.

```
$feedURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'. $youtube->yt_videoId;   

// read feed into SimpleXML object   
$entry = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);

// parse video entry   
$video = $main->parseVideoEntry($entry);
```

I'll keep looking, but thanks in advance if you have a good link for me to look at while I research this problem.

Answer (score 4):

If you visit the url http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/b3a5BgqObEY you'll see "Private video", which is the reason you can't get the feed...

EDIT: You can use the V3 of the API to send an authentificated request; check this url to learn how to do it: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/

Greetings

Comment: You'll need to implement the OAuth 2.0 protocol to authorize access to YouTube private videos: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol

Comment: I did visit that link. I was asking if there was a way to fix the error, but thanks for checking Alex.